# How to write given, when, then for switching tabs to check login

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I want to write a manual test in given, when, then format but I am struggling to write the test in this format for the relevant scenario and wanted to ask for assistance.

This is the manual procedure of the test:

- User logs into a website
- User opens a new tab
- User pastes in url into second tab and they are automatically logged in as it uses same session
- user logs out of website from one of the tabs
- User refresh the other tab and they are automatically logged out of there

I don't know how to write this in the GIVEN, WHEN, THEN style and keep it concise so I would like some assistance please.

I made an attempt but I am not happy with it:

```
Given user opens the homepage
And the user logs in
Then the logout button is displayed
Given user selects another tab
And user opens the homepage
And user logs in
Then the log out button is displayed
When I log out of homepage
Then the login panel is displayed
When I switch tabs 
And I refresh the other homepage
Then the login panel is displayed
```

I'm not really happy with this so can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Hi there, the standards used for Gherkin feature files are all over the place really, the bottom line is that the readability would come down to how the business perceives it, however generally in a single scenario you should only have ***ONE Given*** and ***ONE Then*** i would suggest keeping your scenarios 3 - 5 lines long maximum as a failure in the test would stop other parts of the tests to not run.

for example..


`Given user opens the homepage
And the user inputs credentials
Then user should see (confirmation of logged in)`

next scenario..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Given user opens the homepage
And the user logs in
Then user opens the Url(MainPage) in another tab
And then clicked on the logout button in one of the tab
And able to see the login panel in the same tab
Then User switched to other tab 
And  Refresh the Page or tab 
Then User now able to see the  login panel in other tab also.
```

**Note**:***Given, When, Then***   are the keywords, we are  using to write the Scenarios, so that the code is more readable for the business. They do not have any impact or functionality other than readability.